# Angular 4 website - how we use apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, angular, ios-universal-links, associated-domains, apple-app-site-association

I have created file like apple-app-site-association and move the file to www folder and try access this file from url for universal linking, it always show not found and online validator shows the error.

```
{
“applinks”: {
    “apps”: [],
    “details”: [
        {
            “appID”: “T5TQ36Q2SQ.com.reddit.production”,
            “paths”: [“*”],
        }
    ]
}
```

}

So please any body help me out, how we configure apple-app-site-association file in angular web project. Is there any way return header content type for angular web project instead of view, because apple need content type as application/json

Comment: Guys any recommendation?

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961812/preventing-angular-from-running-when-accessing-static-files-with-no-extension/72153182#72153182)